# Couchbase-lite 1.2.1 views returning old _rev numbers. How to fix

Tags: couchdb, couchbase-lite

=== EDIT Problem solved by rolling back couchbase-lite ===

1. Previously we had couchbase-lite v1.1.0 installed on the phone.
2. We had upgraded to couchbase-lite v1.2.1, then we noticed the problem
3. We rolled back to couchbase-lite v1.1.0, and the problem seems to have resolved

I have a CouchDB server that talks to a Couchbase-lite database. On CouchDB when I update a document that is retrieved by a view; when accessed, the view gives the most recent document.

On the mobile phone this is not the case. How do I get Couchbase-lite to recalculate views?

It seems couchDB has this endpoint:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/compact.html#api-db-view-cleanup

Is there an equivalent on Couchbase-lite?

This endpoint: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/database/post-compact/index.html seems like it will remove old versions of a document.

Will this force the views to retrieve only the latest documents?

=============================

## EDIT in response to first comment below

My exact use case is the following:

1. On the server I have a db called 'db_'. This is CouchDB
2. I replicate all the document from 'db_' to 'db_shadow' (this is so I can reset db_shadow when required). This is also on the server and is CouchDB
3. All design documents are edited on 'db_', and then replicate to 'db_shadow' (i.e. views are edited on the 'db_' database)
4. All the documents are replicated from 'db_shadow' to the mobile phone

When the mobile phone first syncs with the server (i.e. it has no data) then I am able to access the most recent _revs of documents with the following view:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type_ === 'customer') {
        emit(doc.phone_number.toString(), doc);
    };
};
```

So the view IS DEFINITELY on the couchbase-lite design document (since calling the view returns documents).

Comment: You mean you've created a view in Couchbase Lite?  Can you show the exact scenario you are using?  By default, Couchbase Lite will update its views before returning any results from a query on them.

Comment: Hi, it seems that rolling back to a previous version helped. I see you work on the Couchbase software, please let me know if I'm correct/incorrect on the above.

Comment: Couchbase Lite has no direct concept of design documents, although they are there for compatibility sake in the REST API.  What platform are you runnign by the way?

Comment: We replicate a _design/android document from CouchDB to couchbase-lite. From this document we get all the views... I'm not sure what you mean by couchbase-lite having no design documents? I understand that CouchDB uses design documents to hold user-defineable server side code and that they may be treated differently by couchbase. We are running couchbase-lite on Android. I was not involved in development of this so I can't be more specific

Comment: What I mean is that Couchbase Lite has moved on from the concept of design documents in favor of native view functions.  They are kept around for API compatibility sake but I don't think I've heard of anyone using them from CouchDB before (not to say that no one actually has...).  So what you are saying is that you update the document on the server side, but the document remains old on the client side?  Are you running a continuous replication?  Do you have any log error messages from logcat?  If this is easily reproducible then I suggest filing an issue with the repro case.

Comment: Also, can you check to see that the document's properties have changed (i.e. retrieving the doc shows the current result but the view shows an older result?)

Comment: @borrrden. It's difficult for me to check this, since it involves changing Java code in the Android app (we don't have an API that retrieves a single document, our APIs exclusively allow retrieving views). I will try over the next couple days

Answer (score 0):

I guess issue is same with 
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/795.

Could you please try the master branch build from Couchbase custom maven repo?
http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/lite/couchbase-lite-android/0.0.0-710/

Thanks!